# Form field dependencies lost on export/import in EPiServer

Tags: forms, dependencies, content-management-system, episerver, optimizely

We are using Episerver/Optimizely CMS 11.20.7. When exporting a page containing a form containing form fields with dependencies from our production environment and later import it to our acceptance test environment (or vice versa), the form field dependencies are lost:

[image: Text element dependencies]

Is this supposed to work/has anybody successfully done this?

Comment: How did you do the export / import?

Comment: The export/import was done via the "standard" Export Data and Import Data tools in the CMS/Admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

We have been in contact with Optimizely and this is apparently the expected behavior. Form field IDs will have to be manually amended for dependencies after an import.